# Node object is not iterable

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I get this error message, when I try to parse the result set, returned by `MATCH` query. What I want is to somehow convert the resultset to a dictionary. I should say that I know how to access particular fields of the result set - like `row['a']['name']`, but what I do not like is that I can not convert the whole `row['a']` to a dictionary or to get something like `row['a'].keys()`.

So, this is what I tried:

```
res = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (a:Object {id: 1}) return a")
for r in res:
    print r['a']['id'] # this works

for r in res:
    print r['a'].keys() # this does not

#what I want is something like
{x:y for (x,y) in zip(r['a'].keys(), r['a'].values()}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html), it looks like `execute` is returning a `py2neo.cypher.RecordList` of `py2neo.cypher.Record` objects, which can then be iterated over:

```
for r in res:
    for v in r['a']:
        # do something with v
```

Unfortunately, looking at the [source code](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo/blob/56def26c826dd5c593ab6067ee434212433d6d16/py2neo/cypher/core.py), there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to access the column name, without doing a `dir(r)` and filtering the results, e.g. `[c for c in dir(r) if not c.startswith('_')]`.

Edit: Looking at it again, I guess `r` is the `Record` while `r['a']` is something else. You'll have to see what kinda of object `r['a']` is using `type(r['a'])`, and then see if there's a way to access the keys.

Answer (score 1):

The accessors directly attached to the Node object are a shortcut to the `properties` attribute. Therefore you will want to iterate through `r["a"].properties` in the same way you would any other dictionary.